# Replace last 2 numeric values in pandas data frame by row with NAN's

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

The last 2 real numbers in each row of my data were measured with error. I want to replace them with np.NAN. The number of real numbers differs by row (i.e., each row already has some NAN's at differing amount). Column headers indicate measurement number, index was a experimental trial.Values in a cell equal a measurement reading. Some trials had more measurement readings than others;thus, some rows have more NAN's than others.  The below code creates a data frame similar to mine.

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   data = np.array(([1,2,3,4,5,2,np.NaN], 
   [2,2,3,2,3,np.NaN,np.NaN],[4,4,5,1,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.nan]))
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'])
```

The data frame yielded from code that looks similar to mine:

```
       0    1   2   3   4   5   6
    0 1.0  2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 2.0 NAN
    1 2.0  2.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 NAN NAN  
    2 4.0  4.0 5.0 1.0 NAN NAN NAN
```

This is what I want the new data frame to look like:

```
      0    1    2   3   4   5   6
    0 1.0  2.0 3.0 4.0 NAN NAN NAN
    1 2.0  2.0 3.0 NAN NAN NAN NAN  
    2 4.0  4.0 NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN
```

I have tryed counting the NAN and using that to locate the position of the last and second to last numeric values, but it gets me no where.

Ultimately, what I want to do is ignore the NAN's in the original data frame and take the last two real values (i.e., the integers) in a row and replace them with np.NAN. One of the main issues is the position of the last 2 real numbers in a row can differ by row. Making the original data frame look like the new data frame in the above examples.

Comment: Please add more illustration statements.

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Could you specify more what you want to do?

Comment: I added some clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method #1 would be simply to shift everything over by 2 and keep the values which remain non-null:

```
In [61]: df.where(df.shift(-2, axis=1).notnull())
Out[61]: 
     0    1    2    3   4   5   6
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0 NaN NaN NaN
1  2.0  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  4.0  4.0  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Method #2 would be to count the number of non-null values from the right, and only keep non-null values after the second:

```
In [62]: df.where((df.notnull().iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1) > 2))
Out[62]: 
     0    1    2    3   4   5   6
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0 NaN NaN NaN
1  2.0  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  4.0  4.0  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

This isn't as pretty, but would allow for finer levels of customization if we needed to shift differently for each row, for example if it weren't true that we had a row of non-null values followed by null values.